# Why is `a += x` and `a = a + x` implemented differently for a nested list?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, operators

If I build a nested list:

```
nested_list = 3*[[]]
```

and if I then add elements to it

1. `nested_list[1] += [1, 2, 3]`. returns:[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
2. `nested_list[1] = nested_list[1] + [1, 2, 3]`. returns: [[ ], [1, 2, 3], [ ]]

I would have expected to obtain the result of case 2 for both operations.

Why do I obtain a different result in case 1? Is this a design choice of python? What is the logic of the result in case 1?

Comment: The core problem here is that `nested_list = 3*[[]]` is a bad way to create a list of lists: http://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/3001761

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example, you *update* the reference of `nested_list[1]`. Since all 3 slots use the same reference, you see your change 3 times.

In the second example, you're not appending in-place: you create another reference for `nested_list[1]`, which updates only the middle slot of the list of lists, leaving the others with the old reference.

Note that `nested_list = 3*[[]]` to build a nested list is not very useful. You may want to create separate references for all sublists like this:

```
nested_list = [[] for _ in range(3)]
```

Now both operations yield the same result (but the preferred way is `nested_list[1] += ...` since it is way more performant)

This doesn't apply to *immutable* objects like strings, ints, floats, where the `*` operator is not a problem. Applying in-place addition only changes the item it applies to.